# Append element of JSON object in Groovy script

Tags: groovy

- What I am trying to achieve, details of my goal:

I would like to append three elements of my json object in Groovy.

I have this json:

```
[
  {
    "product": "banana",
    "from": "India",
    "price": "42"
  },
  {
    "product": "orange",
    "color": "Spain",
    "price": "5"
  }
]
```

which is from :

```
def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)
println(data)
return data.product
```

- Describe my expected result:

I would like to return the appended triplet string `banana-India-42` and `orange-Spain-5` etc.

- Describe my actual result:

As of right now, with `data.product`, I am successfully seeing `banana` and `orange`

With `data.from`, I am successfully seeing `India` and `Spain`

- What I have tried:

I tried the following:

```
def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)
println(data)
return data.product + data.from + data.price
```

Unfortunately, this is not returning the concatenated string.

- Question

How to return the appended string of the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import groovy.json.*

def filedata = '''
[
  {
    "product": "banana",
    "from": "India",
    "price": "42"
  },
  {
    "product": "orange",
    "from": "Spain",
    "price": "5"
  }
]
'''

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)
return data.collect{"${it.product}-${it.from}-${it.price}"}.join(' ')
```

this code returns `banana-India-42 orange-Spain-5`

Comment: Hello @dagget, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am facing a small technical issue. With ```return data.product``` I do see ```banana```, but using your recommended solution ```return data.collect{"${it.product}"}```, I only see ```[object Object]```

Comment: updated answer with full code